# Extracting CDATA from a soap response in groovy

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, xml-parsing, cdata

Im working on a sample web service at http://webserviceX.NET, somehow it keeps returning it's response within a CDATA. i am trying out to print the response of my request in groovy but it returns null. I was doing this as my practice coding in Groovy. Please bear with me as i just started learning the language and everything about SOAP.

here is my code:

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.8.0' )
import wslite.soap.*
class GlobalWeather {
    def spUrl = ('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx')
    def client = new SOAPClient(spUrl)

    def getCitiesByCountry(String country) {
        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry"){
            body {
                GetCitiesByCountry('xmlns': 'http://www.webserviceX.NET') {
                    CountryName(country)
                }
            }
        }
        def retCountry = response.CitiesByCountryResponse.CitiesByCountryResult
        return retCountry
    }

    def getWeather(def city, def country){
        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather"){
            body{
                GetWeather('xmlns': 'http://www.webserviceX.NET'){
                    CityName(city)
                    CountryName(country)
                }
            }
        }
        def retCountryCity = response.WeatherResponse.WeatherResult
        return retCountryCity
    }

    static void main(String[] args){
        def gWeather = new GlobalWeather()

        println gWeather.getCitiesByCountry('UK')
        println gWeather.getWeather('Kyiv', 'Ukraine')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used incorrect variable names when processing response:

```
def retCountry = response.CitiesByCountryResponse.CitiesByCountryResult
return retCountry
```

instead of:

```
return response.GetCitiesByCountryResponse.GetCitiesByCountryResult
```

and:

```
def retCountryCity = response.WeatherResponse.WeatherResult
return retCountryCity
```

instead of:

```
return response.GetWeatherResponse.GetWeatherResult
```

Omitting `Get` here will not work because this is not a name of a variable (there's no getter) but a node name.

Below You can find corrected script:

```
@Grab(group = 'com.github.groovy-wslite', module = 'groovy-wslite', version = '0.8.0')
import wslite.soap.*

class GlobalWeather {
    def spUrl = ('http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx')
    def client = new SOAPClient(spUrl)

    def getCitiesByCountry(String country) {
        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry") {
            body {
                GetCitiesByCountry('xmlns': 'http://www.webserviceX.NET') {
                    CountryName(country)
                }
            }
        }
        return response.GetCitiesByCountryResponse.GetCitiesByCountryResult
    }

    def getWeather(def city, def country) {
        def response = client.send(SOAPAction: "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather") {
            body {
                GetWeather('xmlns': 'http://www.webserviceX.NET') {
                    CityName(city)
                    CountryName(country)
                }
            }
        }
        return response.GetWeatherResponse.GetWeatherResult
    }
}

def gWeather = new GlobalWeather()

println gWeather.getCitiesByCountry('UK')
println gWeather.getWeather('Kyiv', 'Ukraine')
```

P.S. Upvote for preparing a working example! That's how question should be asked here.

Comment: .@Opal thank you for that very nice explanation of how it works. I am now referring to your answer as my reference for my future practice coding. Thanks so much for the help. Cheers!